TeamCity agents on burst EC2 instances
I am playing with TeamCity and I have a cloud agent profile setup to use an AMI in my account from a previous project (basic Linux machine)
TC can launch a new instance when a build is queued but I think I need to install the agent software on the original instance.
If I install the agent software on a the original instance and make a new AMI, how do I get the agent software to auto start on instance boot?
